# Javascript use one of function parameters a result of another function

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following javascript code (simplified here):

```
function calculate_id() {
if (some_condition_met) {return 1;} else {return 0;}
}
```

I want to call another function like this:

```
function render_page(param1=0 , calculate_id() ) {
...ajax code based on parameters ...
}
```

what is the best (and every browser compatible) way to do that?

thanks for your suggestions

Comment: `some_other_function(calculate_id)` - note the missing `()` after `calculate_id` because you want to *pass* the function, not *call* it.

Comment: I don't believe this function declaration `function render_page(param1=0 , calculate_id() )` is valid syntax; you have to assign the return value of `calculate_id()` to a variable (as you've done with `param1=0`) so it can be used in the function itself. Aside from that, can you elaborate on how you reached the conclusion that this isn't "*the best*" way, or that it's not compatible cross-browser? Using the return value of a function is pretty standard JavaScript. Can you define what "*the best*" means to *you* specifically? Otherwise, this question is opinion-based and not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Do you mean a call `render_page(0, calculate_id())`, or a parameter declaration `function render_page(param1, calculate_id) { … }`?

Comment: @esqew - I have an Android webview with some html , php and javascript code in the webview. There are older Android version also, i cannot really test for every version by myself, that's why i am asking for the best-practice. This is not the usual work i am doing everyday :)

Comment: @FeHora just like @esqew has stated, do it in a way like `function render_page(param1=0 , id = calculate_id())`. It will definitely work on all the browsers.

Comment: You can take a look at [can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=default%20parameters) for browser compatibility

Comment: @PranavRustagi  i have exactly like that at the moment. I just wanted to be absolutely sure, it will not cause problem with older Androids / Chrome versions as javascript evolved. The release date is in 20 days, i really don't want to had mad scientists with not working android app in my office :))

Comment: @A_A thanks for this link, very very helpful for me. I really hope there will be no  Android versions older than version 4

Comment: @FeHora You can also take a look at [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) if you want to use newer features while being backwards compatible

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas that may be useful:

```js
const calculate_id = (someCondition = false) => someCondition ? 1 : 0;

render_page();
render_page_alt(calculate_id);

function render_page(param1 = 0, id = calculate_id() ) {
  console.log(id);
}

function render_page_alt(calc = () => {}, param1 = 1 ) {
  console.log(calc(param1));
}
```